# Clear all FilterQuery in Sitecore.ContentSearch linq query

Tags: c#, linq, solr, sitecore, sitecore8

I can do solr query with

```
var index = ContentSearchManager.GetIndex(IndexName);
var context = index.CreateSearchContext()
var results = context.GetQueryable<SolrCoreModel>().GetResults()...
```

but there's always added in raw solr query fq parameter with indexname

```
&fq=_indexname:(solr_core)
```

How can I remove it and send 'clear' query?

Answer (score 2):

You can not do this with Sitecore and `ContentSearchManager`.

This is how Sitecore stores data in Solr - it splits it in "indexes". You cannot query using Sitecore API and without passing index name to Solr.

When Sitecore indexes any item, e.g. `Home` item, if this is `Home` item from your `master` database, it will be stored with field `_indexname` set e.g. to `sitecore_master_index`. Same item from the `web` database will be marked with `sitecore_web_index`.

Comment: So may I somehow pass it with Query, instead of FilterQuery?

Comment: I'm guessing you would have to skip Sitecore API completely and try low level `Solr.net`. I'm not sure if it's possible. Why do you even try to to this?

Comment: I have custom solr core that I'm using as a 'merged' core for two other cores with different schema. It looks like when something is passed with 'fq' that field should be included in both schemas. 'q' doesn't have such a constraints.

Comment: @Saint how did you tackle that fq in your case because I have the same requirement?